# MYSQL Select MAX Date in a 3 table join grouped by the ID in the 1st table

Tags: mysql, join, max, maxdate

I have three tables, one called **BookingDetails** that stores the client info. 140,000 records

| CustomerRef | Name | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2023-12-17 |
| 2 | Sarah | 2024-06-17 |
| 3 | Fred | 2024-09-10 |
| 4 | Bill | 2022-03-11 |

The second called **BookingRequest** that contains the requests that client has made. 83,000 records

| ID | CustomerRef |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 83000 | 4 |

and the third called **RequestLog**  that stores the request status of each Booking Request. 110,000 records

| ID | RequestID | DateAdded | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-08-17 | Refused |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-08-18 | Pending |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-08-19 | Booked |
| 4 | 3 | 2023-09-14 | Pending |
| 5 | 4 | 2023-09-19 | Pending |
| 6 | 5 | 2023-10-17 | Refused |
| 110000 | 83000 | 2023-10-18 | Pending |

I need to find all current clients that haven't booked, so I am looking to perform a join to return only the MAX(Status) grouped by Client where the expiry date is greater than now. The problem I have is that a client can have multiple booking requests. The query I have done works correctly if a client only has one request, but if a client has a request where the the lastest Status is 'booked' but then has another request where the latest status is 'pending' it is appearing in the list. I need to ONLY show clients where the latest status of ANY of their requests is anything apart from 'booked'.

SELECT BookingDetails.CustomerRef,  BookingDetails.Name, BookingDetails.Expiry, b.Status AS Holidaystatus
FROM BookingDetails
JOIN BookingRequest ON BookingRequest.CustomerRef=  BookingDetails.CustomerRef
INNER JOIN RequestLog a ON a.RequestID=BookingRequest.ID
JOIN (SELECT MAX(DateAdded)  maxdate, RequestID FROM RequestLog GROUP BY RequestID) AS b ON  a.RequestID=b.RequestID AND a.DateAdded=b.maxdate WHERE a.Status != 'Booked' AND DATE(BookingDetails.Expiry) > CURDATE()
GROUP BY   BookingDetails.CustomerRef

What I want to see is

| CustomerRef | Name | Expiry | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Sarah | 2024-06-17 | Pending |
| 3 | Fred | 2024-09-10 | Refused |

What I am seeing is

| CustomerRef | Name | Expiry | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2023-12-17 | Pending |
| 2 | Sarah | 2024-06-17 | Pending |
| 3 | Fred | 2024-09-10 | Refused |

Comment: What was the current date when you wanted to run your query?

Comment: Please format your code ....

Comment: I am confused is the ID in the second table really `RequestID`?  Please make it  more obvious what is linked to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to identify the latest status for each client's requests and then filter based on that result.

```
SELECT
    BD.CustomerRef,
    BD.Name,
    BD.Expiry,
    RL.Status AS HolidayStatus
FROM
    BookingDetails BD
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        BR.CustomerRef,
        MAX(RL.DateAdded) AS MaxDate
    FROM
        BookingRequest BR
    INNER JOIN RequestLog RL ON BR.ID = RL.RequestID
    GROUP BY
        BR.CustomerRef
) LatestStatus ON BD.CustomerRef = LatestStatus.CustomerRef
LEFT JOIN BookingRequest BR ON BD.CustomerRef = BR.CustomerRef
LEFT JOIN RequestLog RL ON BR.ID = RL.RequestID
WHERE
    LatestStatus.MaxDate IS NULL OR LatestStatus.MaxDate = RL.DateAdded
    AND DATE(BD.Expiry) > CURDATE()
    AND (RL.Status IS NULL OR RL.Status != 'Booked');
```

This query first creates a subquery (LatestStatus) to find the maximum date added for each customer's requests. Then, it joins the BookingDetails table with the LatestStatus subquery and the other necessary tables.